# How to get the Objectivc-C selector name in LLVM IR?

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm

I am a beginner to LLVM. I am trying to develop a LLVM pass. This pass will find all the comparisons "self.currentGameID == 2007", and replace it with "true".
I success to find the comparison, the right operand "2007" is easy to confirm, but when I check the function name whether is "currentGameID", I only get the "objc_msgsend".
Here is the code:

```
bool handleComp(ICmpInst *cmpInst) {
    if (!cmpInst->hasOneUse()) {
        return false;
    }
    APInt CmpC = cast<ConstantInt>(cmpInst->getOperand(1))->getValue();
    if (!CmpC) {
        return false;
    }
    auto constIntValue = CmpC.getSExtValue();
    if (constIntValue == 2007) {
        auto BasicBlock = cmpInst->getParent();
        auto preInstruction = cmpInst->getPrevNode();
        if (isa<CallInst>(preInstruction)) {
            CallInst *ci = cast<CallInst>(preInstruction);
            Function *function = ci->getCalledFunction();
            if (function) {
                StringRef name = function->getName();
                errs().write_escaped(name) << '\n';
            } else {
                Function *voidFunc = dyn_cast<Function>(ci->getCalledOperand()->stripPointerCasts());
                StringRef name = voidFunc->getName();
                errs().write_escaped(name) << '\n';
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I get voidFunc name , it is "objc_msgsend"!

Is there anyone can tell me how to get the true selector name "currentGameID"?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a property like `self.currentGameID` is the same as `[self currentGameID]`. That is, they both produce the same Objective-C runtime call of `objc_msgSend(self, @selector(currentGameID))`.

The Objective-C code `if (self.currentGameID == 2007)` will produce (roughly) the following IR:

```
%1 = load i8*, i8** @OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_.0 
%2 = call i64 bitcast (i8* (i8*, i8*, ...)* @objc_msgSend to i64 (i8*, i8*)*)(i8* %0, i8* %1)
%3 = icmp eq i64 %2, 2007
```

So to get the actual selector you can use `ci->getArgOperand(i)` where `i` is either 1 or 2 depending on which version of LLVM you're using.